# Как писать прямые запросы через sqlsrv_query()

Tags: php, sql-server

Можно ли как-то выполнить прямой запрос через sqlsrv_query().

Те есть не так

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Table_1 (id, data) VALUES (?, ?)";
$params = array(1, "some data");

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
```

а вот так примерно

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Table_1 (id, data) VALUES (10, 'somedata')";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
```

без prepare, (я понимаю что это небезопасно, но нужно именно так)
Есть такая возможность?

Comment: так и напишите как есть. а вместо $params пустой массив

Comment: это не безопасно, когда вы не знаете какие данные подставляете в запрос. То есть когда подставляются данные пользовательского ввода. Если вы вполне знаете что там будут какие-то 2 ваших строки, то ничего опасного в этом нет.